# Need Help Related Laravel Project Installation

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am very new to laravel. I have installed on my xampp server. I had download a small to do app to learn it. I was installing

App Url: https://github.com/csoutham/laravel-todo-app

I had found instructions there to install it.

When run this command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

It displays the following error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid
>   catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: create table `migrati
>
>   ons` (`migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default
>   character set utf8 co   llate utf8_unicode_ci)
>
> migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--path[="..."]]
>   [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]

Comment: Hi, in the step 2)  of the docs you've mentioned you should create database "laravel-todo-app" and put credentials (i.e. dbname, username and password) to "app/config/database.php". The error could be caused by incorrect creds, to check that run command in command line "mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASE", where DATABASE, USERNAME^ PASSWORD are creds you put  "app/config/database.php". It command fails - error in creating dB

Comment: i have added correct credentials, you can also check this in issue tab in above github url, that issue is raised by me, i had soecified my credenials there

Comment: database is already created

Comment: check the issue here : https://github.com/csoutham/laravel-todo-app/issues/2

Comment: HERE dB name goes to DB_DATABASE env variable >> "'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel-todo-app')," but HERE it is taken from db_name >> "'database' => getenv('db_name')," Please make the same env variables for dB name i.e database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),

Comment: I had changed db_name to db_database but the problem is still there ! :(

Comment: what is the output of "echo $DB_DATABASE" in command line?

Comment: when i write "echo $DB_DATABASE" in cmd, it is displaying $DB_DATABASE

Comment: run command without quotes - echo $DB_DATABASE, if output is "$DB_DATABASE" , something is wrong. It must be "laravel-todo-app"

Comment: yes, i had runned without quote(""), it is still same output i.e $DB_DATABASE

Comment: you can try to set dB name directly - 'database' => 'laravel-todo-app', (in app/config/database.php)

Comment: if it fails, show please updated config/database.php again

Comment: i had tried and it works but  now the error is  


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'laravel-todo-app'



migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]

Comment: much better, dB is there. please do the same for username and password

Comment: when i changed config to this   'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'database'  => 'laravel-todo-app',
   'username'  => 'root',
   'password'  => '',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
  ),

Comment: it works, thanks for help

Comment: you are welcome, good luck

Comment: Really thankful for your help, thanks #sr3z